# Correct name for a combinatoric structure

Tags: combinatorics

An outcomes of an experiment of 6 coin tosses is 'H H T H T T'. What is the correct name for this entity? Can it be called a **String** over the alphabet{H,T}, of length 6?
Subramanyan

Comment: A more specific term, if you wish to capture the probability context, is a [Bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial).

Answer (score 0):

While *string* would make sense to many, and it conveys the notion of ordered elements with possible repetition, it is more common in combinatorics to say an *arrangement* or a [permutation with repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition).

Once the *alphabet* (set of symbols) is identified, we might specify the length $k$ of such a string by the designation $k$-arrangement.

As combinatorial objects go, these are fairly easy to count.  If the size of the alphabet is $n$, there are $n^k$ possible $k$-arrangements.  The difficulty of counting is greater if some or all of the symbols are assigned limits on how many times they can appear in the arrangement.  If the exact number of each symbol's appearances is known, the counting problem is again easy, a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients):

$$ \frac{k!}{k_1! \cdot k_2! \cdot \ldots \cdot k_n!} $$

where $k_i$ is the exact frequency of the $i$th symbol ($i=1,\ldots,n$).

Comment: Grateful to find that even naïve questions are answered with patience.Emboldened to ask another: The standard Combinatoric entity of collecting one element from each of many given sets and forming one set. Five shirts and 3 trousers. How many dress sets?. Does that have a name? My grandson has named it 'Ofe (One from each) collection'!

Comment: Grateful to find that even naïve questions are answered with patience.Emboldened to ask another: The standard Combinatoric entity of collecting one element from each of many given sets and forming one set. Five shirts and 3 trousers. How many dress sets?. Does that have a name? My grandson has named it 'Ofe (One from each) collection'!

Comment: This construction is commonly called the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).  The set of (ordered) pairs is easily counted, and the size of the Cartesian product is the product of the two sizes of the sets (five times three = ?).

Comment: Thanks  But a Cartesian product is 'ordered', and the source set/s need not be distinct from one another. They can be, and often are, identical.                                                                                                     I suppose there is no special name for a collection from distinct sets, and where the order in the collection does not matter.                Subramanyan

Comment: The *pairs* that make up the Cartesian product are called ordered pairs because the entries are distinctly chosen.  In your case the choice of a shirt can be distinguished from the choice of trousers.